# The intent flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP" is not working

Tags: android, android-intent

This flag not working when try to the activities like
A-B-C and then again launch activity  C then the `onNewIntent()` not invoking also the activity c will be launced

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example that can be used to reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: There is actually no question in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to relaunch the activity from its own just use

```
startActivity(getIntent())
```

Comment: Don't use answers as comments.

Comment: @Zoe I think you wrote the wrong way, it's supposed to be *don't write comments as answers* :)

Comment: @Gourav Nope. If you use answers as comments, that implies having an answer that partially or entirely contains comments. The other half of the answer is an actual answer though.

Comment: I just said for the current situation. The OP doesn't have enough reputation and at that time you were saying *Don't use answers as comments*. Anyways let it be.